# When I get the fields from my graphql query in Reactjs it does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql

I'm trying to get the field called **fecha_dia_hoy** and **fecha**, however, when I do this.props, I always get the match and data props but I do not understand why I can not get the fields if I see that the request is done correctly after calling the DiaComoHoyNoticia and News components.

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Noticia from '../../views/Noticia';
import DiaComoHoyNoticia from '../DiaComoHoyNoticia';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const query = gql`
query queryPost($id: Int!) {
    post(id: $id) {
      id
      fecha
      fecha_dia_hoy
    }
  }
`;

export class DiaComoHoyWrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // TODO: Realizar la busqnoueda del articulo con Grahpql
    // Creador =, contenido, fecha , etc.
    super(props);

    //this.id = props.data;

  }

  render() {
    this.id = this.props.match.params.id;
    const { id } = this.props.match.params.id;

    const today = new Date();
    const todayDate = today.getDate();
    const todayMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
    if (this.props.match.params.categoryId == 28) {
      return (
        <div>
          <DiaComoHoyNoticia dia={todayDate} mes={todayMonth} id={this.id}/>
          <Noticia id={this.props.match.params.id} />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Noticia id={this.props.match.params.id} />
      );
    }
  }
}

DiaComoHoyWrapper.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    currentSortItem: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    error: PropTypes.shape({ message: PropTypes.string }),
  }).isRequired,
};

DiaComoHoyWrapper.defaultProps = {};

const queryOptions = {
  options: props => ({
    variables: {
      id: props.match.params.id,
    },
  }),
};
export default graphql(query, queryOptions)(DiaComoHoyWrapper);
```

What could be happening? I have always done this in the other components and it works, but I do not understand why this does not work. thank you!

Edit: I add the schema of Post:

```
import {
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLBoolean,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLObjectType,
} from 'graphql';

// App Imports
import PostType from '../type';
import { getAll, getById } from '../resolvers';

const ListPostType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'listpost',
  description: '...',
  fields: () => ({
    rows: {
      type: new GraphQLList(PostType),
    },
    count: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
  }),
});

// Post All
export const posts = {
  type: ListPostType,
  args: {
    first: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    offset: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    titulo: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    mes: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    dia: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    contenido: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    sort: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    destacado: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean,
    },
    order: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },
    categoria: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    parent: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    tag: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
    equipo: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    },
  },
  resolve: getAll,
};

// Post By ID
export const post = {
  type: PostType,
  args: {
    id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
  },
  resolve: getById,
};
```

Comment: please add you graphql schema for post type.

Comment: Ready @galkin !

Comment: Can you please clarify whether it's `props.data`, `props.data.post` or the individual fields (`fecha_dia_hoy`, `fecha`) that is null. Also, whether the value(s) in question are in fact null or undefined.